# Why aren't there numpy.testing.assert_array_greater, assert_array_less_equal, assert_array_true, etc?

Tags: unit-testing, numpy

In `numpy.testing`, there's `assert_array_less` and `assert_array_equal`, but there isn't an `assert_array_less_equal` function or even an `assert_array_greater`. I have two questions:

1. Is there a reason these functions are missing, but `assert_array_less` is not?
2. I've written my own versions of these missing functions by using numpy.testing.util.assert_array_compare, e.g.:

```
def assert_array_greater(aa, bb):
  assert_array_compare(np.greater, aa, bb)
```

Is this safe? I.e. is there a reason why `assert_array_compare` is hidden away in `numpy.testing.util`, rather than living in `numpy.testing`?

Forgive my paranoia; it just seems weird that these functions don't exist, to the extent that I fear it's for some good reason that I shouldn't be working around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`np.testing` is a module that collects tests and tools used by various of the `numpy` unittesting files.  So it's designed more for internal use, than for end user use.  So the simple answer would be that those extra tests aren't needed.

But looking at the source code for one of those functions:

```
def assert_array_less(x, y, err_msg='', verbose=True):
    assert_array_compare(operator.__lt__, x, y, err_msg=err_msg,
                         verbose=verbose,
                         header='Arrays are not less-ordered',
                         equal_inf=False)
```

It looks like it would be easy to write a variation the uses one of the other `operator` methods.

The 'root' of `np.testing` is `numpy/testing/__init__.py`, which is a short file.  Looks like its main task is `from .utils import *`.  This is typical subpackage organization.  The `__init__` collects the necessary imports, but often doesn't have significant code of its own.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any guesses as to why they use operator.__lt__ rather than numpy.less? (As in, is there a good reason why I should as well?)

Comment: That file only uses `operator` twice.  I think `operator.__lt__(a,b)` delegates to `a.__lt__(b)`, the same as `a<b`.  `np.less` is `ufunc` version, which at some compiled level probably ends up calling the same code, but details like that can be hard to trace.